# Problemas ao percorrer objeto em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, react

estou consumindo uma API e exibindo dados com React.
A API retorna o seguinte Json:

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Outros",
        "abreviacao": "OUT",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Outros"
    },
    "1349": {
        "id": 1349,
        "nome": "Ipatinga",
        "abreviacao": "IPA",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Ipatinga"
    },
    "1371": {
        "id": 1371,
        "nome": "Cuiabá",
        "abreviacao": "CUI",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Cuiabá"
    },
    "1390": {
        "id": 1390,
        "nome": "Icasa",
        "abreviacao": "ICA",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Icasa"
    },
    "2190": {
        "id": 2190,
        "nome": "Oeste",
        "abreviacao": "OES",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Oeste"
    },
    "2193": {
        "id": 2193,
        "nome": "Duque de Caxias",
        "abreviacao": "DUQ",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Duque de Caxias"
    },
    "2197": {
        "id": 2197,
        "nome": "Americana",
        "abreviacao": "AME",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Americana"
    },
    "2554": {
        "id": 2554,
        "nome": "Grêmio Prudente",
        "abreviacao": "PRU",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Grêmio Prudente"
    },
    "2565": {
        "id": 2565,
        "nome": "Luverdense",
        "abreviacao": "LUV",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Luverdense"
    }

}
```

Gostaria de exibir estes dados em uma tabela, mas ao tentar percorrer com map, tenho um erro:

```
TypeError: times.map is not a function
```

Segue o script em JS:

```
class App extends Component{

  state = {
    times: [],
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    const response = await api.get('')
    this.setState({times: response.data})
    console.log(response.data)
  }
  render(){
    const {times} = this.state
    return(
      <div>
        {times.map(time =>(
          <li key={time.id}>
            {time.id}
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu `JSON` é um objeto onde cada chave desse objeto também representa outro objeto, bem diferente do que interar sobre um `array` de objetos que com o `map` é fácil, mas, como resolver esse problema, primeiro deve identificar cada chave desse objeto com [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) retornando somente as chaves, e depois disso é fácil percorrer cada item desse objeto e resgatar seus valores, exemplo:

```js
function App() {
  const data = {
    "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Outros",
        "abreviacao": "OUT",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Outros"
    },
    "1349": {
        "id": 1349,
        "nome": "Ipatinga",
        "abreviacao": "IPA",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Ipatinga"
    },
    "1371": {
        "id": 1371,
        "nome": "Cuiabá",
        "abreviacao": "CUI",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Cuiabá"
    },
    "1390": {
        "id": 1390,
        "nome": "Icasa",
        "abreviacao": "ICA",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Icasa"
    },
    "2190": {
        "id": 2190,
        "nome": "Oeste",
        "abreviacao": "OES",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Oeste"
    },
    "2193": {
        "id": 2193,
        "nome": "Duque de Caxias",
        "abreviacao": "DUQ",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Duque de Caxias"
    },
    "2197": {
        "id": 2197,
        "nome": "Americana",
        "abreviacao": "AME",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Americana"
    },
    "2554": {
        "id": 2554,
        "nome": "Grêmio Prudente",
        "abreviacao": "PRU",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Grêmio Prudente"
    },
    "2565": {
        "id": 2565,
        "nome": "Luverdense",
        "abreviacao": "LUV",
        "escudos": {
            "60x60": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_65x65.png",
            "45x45": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_45x45.png",
            "30x30": "https://s.glbimg.com/es/sde/f/organizacoes/escudo_default_30x30.png"
        },
        "nome_fantasia": "Luverdense"
    }

  };
  function loadObjectItems() {  
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(data).map(time => (
          <li key={data[time].id} style={{listStyleType:'none'}}>
            <img src={data[time].escudos['30x30']} border="0" />
            {data[time].id} - {data[time].nome}
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div>{loadObjectItems()}</div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

o código principal para tirar a sua duvida é:

```
<div>
    {Object.keys(data).map(time => (
      <li key={data[time].id}>
        {data[time].id} - {data[time].nome}
      </li>
    ))}
 </div>
```

onde o [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) traz as chaves dos outros objetos e com essa informação pode ser mapeado e resgatar cada objeto com suas informações e finalizando mostrar a informações como no exemplo completo.

A resposta do @user140828 é uma reposta direta e mostra com isso que não precisa mudar nada no seu código, só a forma de colocar o estado de um `array`, mas, quis trazer essa solução para que entenda realmente o que acontece e também outra forma de resolver.

Comment: Ótimo, me ajudou muito a entender, obrigado Virgilio.

Comment: os votos negativos começaram de novo assombrar o stackoverflow, fora os outros problemas já citados ..,

Comment: Virgilio, tem outro endpoint nessa mesma API que retorna o objeto, como faria neste caso?

{
    "atletas": [],
    "esquema_id": 0,
    "rodada_atual": 1,
    "patrimonio": 0,
    "valor_time": 0,
    "capitao_id": null,
    "pontos": null,
    "pontos_campeonato": null,
    "time": {
        "assinante": false,
        "cadastro_completo": true,
        "simplificado": false,
        "clube_id": 264,
        "esquema_id": 1,
        "tipo_adorno": 2,
        "tipo_camisa": 1,
        "tipo_escudo": 1,
        "temporada_inicial": 2016
    }
}

Comment: Então, você pode fazer a mesma coisa que foi passado na resposta que você aceitou, pelo visto ela foi mais fácil para você entender o problema inicial da sua pergunta além do mais quando você tem outra duvida deve ser gerado outra pergunta, faz isso gera uma outra pergunta @AdrianoValentim pra que tenha mais pessoas para responder, a lógica é a mesma, e você ai no comentário não postou qual é a sua duvida!

Answer (score 1):

O que você está recebendo da sua API não é um array, é um objeto que está indexando os times pelos seus ids.

Como `map` é um método de objetos do tipo `array`, não tem como invoca-lo no objeto que você recebeu como resposta da sua API.

Para tratar isso, você pode converter o objeto num array, ou mantê-lo como objeto e iterar sobre suas propriedades.

Exemplo de como tratar esse caso convertendo o objeto num array:

```
async componentDidMount(){
  const response = await api.get('')
  this.setState({ times: Object.values(response.data) })
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Funcionou.